# Reporting Services Webparts not Available in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, web-part, reporting-services

Firstly, I work as a DBA and have very limited understanding about how everything hangs together in SharePoint, so apologies if this is something pretty basic.

We have just recently upgraded our WSS 3.0 site to SharePoint 2010. This was done by setting up a new server, installing SharePoint 2010 and then following the migration/upgrade process outline in [this article](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/cory-granata/sharepoint2k7-to-2k10-migration-using-db-attach-method/).

All but one item appears to be working with the new SharePoint 2010 site. On the old 2007 site the home page had an embedded SQL Reporting Services report using the Report Viewer web part.

As this upgrade also involved an upgrade from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012, we need to replace/edit the web part. When accessing the site through Internet Explorer I can create a new page, add the Report Viewer web part and successfully view the report. Editing the home page via the same method doesn't allow me to change the section that contains the report. When I edit the page via SharePoint Designer 2010, I can see that the webpart appears to have been put in the `PlaceHolderMain` section of the home page.

When I edit that section and try to add the Report Viewer web part, the Reporting Services web part aren't listed. Is there anything else I need to setup/install so I can add the web part using SharePoint Designer?

Please note that using integrated mode is not an option.

Comment: Please check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159772.aspx#bkmk_installingwebparts